# Cause of boto3 error "An error occurred (Unavailable)...Tags could not be retrieved"?

Tags: exception, boto3, botocore

I just started getting this error on a script that hasn't changed. Updating to boto3==1.4.3 had no effect. Doesn't look like throttling, does it? Not sure where to go with this one, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 251, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 537, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (Unavailable)
when calling the DescribeSecurityGroups operation (reached max retries: 4):
Tags could not be retrieved.
```

Edited to add: As noted in comment below, this is coming from a seemingly innocuous call to `describe_security_groups()`.

***Another update: OK, this was transient and is no longer happening. Le sigh. Maybe some timeout due to network issues or something. I'll leave it up on SO for now, in case someone sees this and has a flash of insight.***

Comment: Where is the script?

Comment: This comes up deep in my own library and could take some time to isolate reproducibly in non-proprietary code. It may also require access to specifically configured AWS resources. Consequently, unfortunately, I don't have a code fragment for it. I was hoping for a suggestion on the general meaning or implication of "Unavailable" and what might be happening with Tags. All I can say right now is it happens in a call to ``describe_security_groups()``.